# how to setup application of Activiti for multi-instance

Tags: java, activiti, workflow-engine

I'm working on application using the workflow engine Activiti and plan to setup multi-instance for this application. is there any thing to consider for Activiti when it becomes multi-instance?

for example there is timer event can be set that after some given time period, task A will complete and move to task B. if it is multi-instance setup, which instance will handle the above processing? or there is some setting to specify a instance to handle time-related event?